# Contar campos null y no null, agrupando por otro campo

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy construyendo un consulta que me diga la cantidad de campos que están nulos y la cantidad de campos que contengan algún contenido.

**Datos**. Esta es mi tabla:

```
CREATE TABLE opciones ( ID int(11) NOT NULL, 
                        id_pregunta int(50) DEFAULT NULL, 
                        idenc int(50) DEFAULT NULL, 
                        valor int(50) DEFAULT NULL, 
                        hallazgo varchar(250) COLLATE utf8mb4_spanish_ci DEFAULT NULL, 
                        Accion varchar(250) COLLATE utf8mb4_spanish_ci DEFAULT NULL, 
                        fecha date NOT NULL, hora date NOT NULL ) 
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_spanish_ci; 


INSERT INTO opciones (ID, id_pregunta, idenc, valor, hallazgo, Accion, fecha, hora) 
      VALUES(73, 21, 16, 1, NULL, NULL, '0000-00-00', '0000-00-00'),
            (74, 22, 16, 1, NULL, NULL, '0000-00-00', '0000-00-00'),
            (75, 21, 16, 1, 'Se tiene un hallazgo? ', 'Cual es la acciÃ³n correctiva ', '0000-00-00', '0000-00-00'),
            (76, 22, 16, 0, 'Se tiene un hallazgo? ', 'Cual es la acciÃ³n correctiva ', '0000-00-00', '0000-00-00'),
            (77, 21, 16, 1, 'Se tiene un hallazgo? ', 'Cual es la acciÃ³n correctiva ', '0000-00-00', '0000-00-00'),
```

```html
-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `respuestas`
--

CREATE TABLE `respuestas` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `texto` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8mb4_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `idenc` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_spanish_ci;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `respuestas`
--

INSERT INTO `respuestas` (`id`, `texto`, `idenc`) VALUES
(31, 'El personal esta usando el EPP definido en el estÃ', 19),
(32, 'sensores y/o guardas en funcionamiento?', 19),
(33, 'seÃ±alamientos y salidas de emergencia estan en bu', 19),
(34, 'las instrucciones de trabajo estan presentes y dis', 19),
(35, 'la 1era pieza esta identificada y disponible en el', 19),
(36, 'la hoja de mantenimiento autonomo esta actualizada', 19),
(37, 'el operador realiza su operacion de acuerdo a la i', 19),
(38, 'materiales identificados y en su caso segregados', 19),
(39, 'registro de calidad realizados', 19),
(40, 'hay registros de liberaciÃ³n de primera pieza', 19),
(41, 'pieza master / muestras NG - OK disponibles', 19),
(42, 'los indicadores estan posteados y actualizados', 19),
(43, '', 19);

--
```

**Resultado esperado**. Quiero obtener 2 campos por cada uno (uno con el total de `null` y el otro con el resto)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero que me agrupe por id de pregunta, sumando la cantidad de `null`/no `null` por campo.

**¿Qué intenté?**

1. Tengo lo siguiente, pero no me trae los campos `null`:

   ```
   SELECT a.texto as titulo, 
          SUM(CASE WHEN b.valor = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "si", 
          SUM(CASE WHEN b.valor = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "NO", 
          SUM( IF(b.hallazgo IS NOT NULL, 1, 0)), 
          SUM( IF(b.Accion IS NOT NULL, 1, 0)) 
          FROM respuestas a 
          INNER JOIN opciones b 
                ON a.id = b.id_pregunta 
          WHERE a.idenc = 18 
          GROUP BY b.id_pregunta
   ```

   Solo me suma los campos pero no me separa por id. Actualmente me manda esto

   ```
   campo 1 = 3 accion 3 hallazgo
   campo 2 = 3 accion 3 hallazgo 
   campo 3 = 3 accion 3 hallazgo
   ```

   Pero quiero:

   ```
   campo 1 = 1 accion 1 hallazgo
   campo 2 = 0 accion 0 hallazgo 
   campo 3 = 2 accion 2 hallazgo
   ```
2. Esta es la consulta que intenté luego:

   ```
   SELECT a.texto as titulo,b.id_pregunta,
   SUM(CASE WHEN b.valor = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "si",
   SUM(CASE WHEN b.valor = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "NO",
   SUM( IF(b.id_pregunta = a.id and b.hallazgo IS NOT NULL, 1, 0)) as hallazgos,
   SUM( IF(b.id_pregunta = a.id and b.Accion IS NOT NULL, 1, 0)) as acciones,
   SUM( IF(b.id_pregunta = a.id and b.hallazgo IS NULL, 1, 0)) as no hallazgos,
   SUM( IF(b.id_pregunta = a.id and b.Accion IS NULL, 1, 0)) as no acciones
   FROM respuestas a INNER JOIN opciones b ON a.id = b.id_pregunta WHERE a.idenc = 19
   GROUP BY a.id,a.texto,b.id_pregunta
   ```

   Este es el resultado que actualmente obtengo:

   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Pregunta**. ¿Cómo puedo obtener, para cada uno de los 2 campos (`accion` y `hallazgo`), la suma de los `null`s en una columna y la suma de los no `null` en otra columna, agrupando por `id_pregunta`?

Comment: ¿Cuál es la estructura de la(s) tabla(s) involucradas.

Comment: Considero que la pregunta es muy buena.

Comment: @NicolaStrappazzon Puede ser interesante, pero no buena: no sabemos cómo son las tablas en las que está buscando, qué datos está obteniendo o qué entiende por *que no tengan contenido*.

Comment: @antoniosanchez no añadas mas datos en los comentarios. En lugar de eso, pulsa en [edit]  y añádelos ahi para una mejor visualización

Comment: @AntonioSanchez Desconozco detalles de la lógica empleada, pero te sugiero que uses el tipo de dato TIME para la columna hora, o unas las dos columnas fecha y hora y uses un TIMESTAMP, puede que te quede mejor.

Comment: @antonio edité bastante tu pregunta, intentando ordenar lo que estás preguntando. Si hay algo que esté mal, no dudes en **[edit]** para corregirlo.

Comment: @antoniosanchez falta el CREATE TABLE y el INSERT de la tabla respuestas.

Comment: @NicolaStrappazzon ya esta

Comment: Gracias @antoniosanchez, pero los datos de ambas tablas son inconsistentes, trata de evitarlo, posiblemente otras personas traten de usar éste ejemplo y no les funcione.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Los valores de tipo NULL quieren decir "No tengo un valor definido" y se tratan
de una forma particular, en el siguiente ejemplo se muestra como contar:

```
USE test;

CREATE TABLE foo (
  id              BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  attribute_name  CHAR(1),
  attribute_value CHAR(1),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

INSERT INTO foo (attribute_name, attribute_value)
VALUES ('X', NULL),('Y', 'A'),('Y', 'B'),('Z', '');
```

Insertamos 4 registros, solo uno se considera NULL y los otros tres NOT NULL. Por último hacemos un SELECT agrupando por attribute_name y hacemos una especie de contador para los que son NULL y NOT NULL.

```
SELECT
  attribute_name,
  SUM(IF(attribute_value IS NULL, 1, 0)) AS 'Si',
  SUM(IF(attribute_value IS NOT NULL, 1, 0)) AS 'No'
FROM foo
GROUP BY attribute_name;
```

Comment: si es como tu lo comentas solo que me agrupa todo. y quiero que me agrupe por pregunta ejemplo pregunta 1   =  1 hallazgo 1 acción pregunta 2   =   0 hallazgo 0 acción y lo que hace es pregunta 1   =  1 hallazgo 1 acción pregunta 2   =   1 hallazgo 1

Comment: @antoniosanchez puedes poner en el enunciado de la pregunta un ejemplo de salida que esperas? igual como haz hecho con los datos de ejemplo.

Comment: @antonio estoy votando por rechazar tu sugerencia de edición en esta respuesta, porque creo que debería ser una edición en tu pregunta, y no en la respuesta de Nicola

Comment: @Nicola edité bastante la pregunta. Sería bueno que lo revises para verificar que no le esté cambiando el sentido (y como ejemplo de cómo se puede mejorar una pregunta)

Comment: @antoniosanchez Volví a hacer el ejemplo según el nuevo planteamiento, espero que este acorde a tus necesidades.